# Dagger - nested injections, is it necessary to call inject()?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I'm new to Dagger and at the begininig I face some issues. I have simple structure so far in my project. My injection module:

```
@Module(
    injects = {GameBoardFragment.class, GameManager.class},
    complete = false,
    library = true
)

public class GameObjectsProviderModule {
private final Application mApplication;

public GameObjectsProviderModule(Application application){
    this.mApplication = application;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public GameManager provideGameManager(){
    return new GameManager();
}

@Provides
public Board getBoard(){
    return new Board();
}

@Provides @Singleton @ForApplication Context provideAppContext() {
    return mApplication;
}
```

My simplified custom app class looks like that:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
private static ObjectGraph mApplicationGraph;

@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mApplicationGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new GameObjectsProviderModule(this));
}

public static ObjectGraph getObjectGraph(){
    return mApplicationGraph;
}
}
```

And now, my fragment looks like that:

```
public class GameBoardFragment extends Fragment {

@Inject
GameManager mGameManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MyApp.getObjectGraph().inject(this);

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_board, container, false);
    findViews(root);
    confViews();

    return root;
}
}
```

And finally my GameManager class

```
public class GameManager  {

    @Inject Board mBoard;

    public GameManager(){
        MyApp.getObjectGraph().inject(this);
    }
}
```

Andy hey, it works! Great. But my question is why it doesn't work in case I comment out this line:

```
MyApp.getObjectGraph().inject(this);
```

Do we have always explicitly call inject() function to make all necessary injections take place event in nested objects? 
It looks not, as shows coffe maker example:

https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/simple/src/main/java/coffee

Why then I have to call inject() in GameManager class to get it working?

---

Edit:

The consturctor injection approach works just fine.

But for future use I tried to get field injection running, and so far I haven't succeed.

I commented out both @Provide methods from module and I made my GameManager look like this:

```
@Singleton
public class GameManager  {

@Inject Board mBoard;

@Inject
  public GameManager(){
}
}
```

and Board:

```
public class Board {

  @Inject
  public Board() {
  }
}
```

However mBoard doesn't get instantiated. I will try more and I suppose I figure out the proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use constructor injection (like for example the [Thermosiphon](https://github.com/square/dagger/blob/master/examples/simple/src/main/java/coffee/Thermosiphon.java) does), and avoid field injection unless necessary. For example, let your `GameManager` have the `Board` as a constructor argument:

```
@Singleton
public class GameManager  {

  private final Board mBoard;

  @Inject
  public GameManager(final Board board){
      mBoard = board;
  }
}
```

Dagger will use this constructor to create an instance of the `GameManager` (hence the `@Inject` annotation), and notice it needs a `Board` instance. Using the `ObjectGraph`, it will create a `Board` first, and use that instance to create the `GameManager`. You can remove the `@Provides GameManager` method if you do it this way.

In your case, you have a `@Provides Board` method in your module. If you add an `@Inject` annotation to your `Board` constructor, you can remove this provides-method from your module:

```
public class Board {

  @Inject
  public Board() {
  }
}
```

---

If you don't want to use constructor injection, the problem is that you told Dagger that you want to create your `GameManager` instance yourself (because you have the `@Provides GameManager` method). If you remove this method, and let Dagger create it for you like above but without the `Board` parameter in the constructor, Dagger will also notice the `@Inject Board` field and inject that as well.

---

A final remark. Remove the `library = true` and `complete = false` statements! These are not necessary at all in this example. Only add them if you really know what you're doing. By not having them, Dagger will create compile-time errors to notify you that something is wrong. If you do include them, you're telling Dagger "Hey, I know what I'm doing, don't worry, it's all correct", when in fact it isn't.

---

**Edit**

A quote from the Dagger1 site:

> If your class has @Inject-annotated fields but no @Inject-annotated
>   constructor, Dagger will use a no-argument constructor if it exists.
>   Classes that lack @Inject annotations cannot be constructed by Dagger.

I do not use this method very often, so I could be wrong. I think this means that you should remove the `@Inject` annotation from your constructor, like so:

```
@Singleton
public class GameManager  {

  @Inject Board mBoard;

  public GameManager(){ // Or remove the constructor entirely since it's empty
  }
}
```

Since there is an `@Inject` annotation on the `Board` field, Dagger will know to use the no-argument constructor.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation! You have cleared my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue as most of the dagger examples everywhere use a Module with Provides and I had a hard time finding a complete example that just does not use Provides.

I created this one. It uses field injection (not constructor injection) and works just fine through the hierarchy without requiring any call to inject. I am using Dagger 1.2.2.

Main.java

```
import javax.inject.*;
import dagger.*;
import dagger.ObjectGraph;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new CarModule());
        Car car = objectGraph.get(Car.class);
        car.start();
    }
}
```

CarModule.Java

```
import dagger.Module;

@Module(injects = Car.class)
public class CarModule {

}
```

Car.Java

```
import javax.inject.*;

public class Car {
    @Inject public Engine engine;

    @Inject Car() {
        System.out.println("Car constructor");
    }
    public void start() {
        engine.start();
    }

}
```

Engine.Java

```
import javax.inject.*;
public class Engine {
    @Inject WaterPump waterPump;

    Engine() {
        System.out.println("Engine Constructor");
    }
    void start() {
        waterPump.run();
        System.out.println("starting engine.");
    }
}
```

WaterPump.Java

```
import javax.inject.*;
public class WaterPump {
    @Inject WaterPump() {
        System.out.println("WaterPump Constructor.");
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("WaterPump running.");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Car constructor
Engine Constructor
WaterPump Constructor.
WaterPump running.
starting engine.
```

Without The `CarModule` that declares it injects Car.Class this does not work. You get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No
>   inject registered for members/Car. You must explicitly add it to the
>   'injects' option in one of your modules.

But notice that `CarModule` does not `@Provides` anything. It is dagger that automatically creates all the dependencies using the object graph.

Also note that you don't have to place an `@Inject` annotation on the default constructor if you have a `@Inject` field in the class. For `Car` class I used it on both the constructor and the field and in `Engine` class I used it just for the field and not for the constructor and it works fine as documented.

Comment: there wrong into your answer, you had declare `Engine` class twice *As* `WaterPump` class declaration the same as `Engine` class

Comment: I have similar unresolved issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093671/dagger-field-injection-not-working-with-simple-java-classes but I am using dagger2. I dont know what i am missing. Any input is highly appreciated.